# how do i add Editable Dropdownlist using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Html helper for adding dropdown list..

```
 @Html.DropDownList("builds", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["BuildList"], "Select-Build", new { @Id = "builds"})
```

I want to make it **Editable DropDownList** Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you mean type in your own value in addition to selecting from the items, you cant. You would need an auto complete type custom control (e.g. jquery ui)

Comment: please explain your question, do you mean that you want to add and remove items from the dropdown list. or do something like @StephenMuecke has described?

Comment: Amila, I just want to get my dropdown element as editable mode like:when i click on it,element shows all option and a text box over it as editable mode.Is it possible using @html helper (MVC) ...?

Comment: @AdityaK, No, not using the standard helpers. You would need to write your own helper to generate the html you want (and probably a jquery plugin depending on what behavior you want)